# Import .dat file in JS

Tags: javascript, opl

This may seem like a silly question as I am starting to study JS...
I have a .dat file called `adressCoordinates` looking like this :

```
addressBase = {
    <1.9600642,48.4508028,  "39 Rue des Pavillons", 91410, "Authon-la-Plaine", "France">,
    <1.9597052,48.4506145,  "33 Rue des Pavillons", 91410, "Authon-la-Plaine", "France">,
    …
}
```

With the help of a JS function, I'd like to return the longitude/latitude coordinates of an address passed by a parameter.

```
function getAddressCoordinates (address) {
    // search address in file
    return {
        longitude: longitude, 
        latitude: latitude
    };
}
```

I have no idea how to do this, although i saw in JS documentation that you could import modules like this: `import * as data from 'path/adressCoordinates.dat';` but this does not work as it is not a JS file.

What would be a correct/elegant way of doing this? (any documentation link would be greatly appreciated)

Thanks !

Comment: You could use `fetch` to open the file (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). However, that is only part of your problem. The the other part is the processing of your `dat` file. If you were able to convert to XML or jSON, parsing would be rather simple as parsing them is built into the browser.

Comment: I'm not planning on using JS as part of a web-app, but with IBM's OPL (I dont know if that changes anything)